# How to prevent trimming of sbt dependencyTree output

Tags: sbt

Is it possible to configure sbt such that output from `sbt dependencyTree` is not trimmed?

Fragment of trimmed output:

```
[info]   | | | | | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:2.12...
[info]   | | | | | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:2.14.0
[info]   | | | | | | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.14.0 (evicted by: ..
[info]   | | | | | | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.14.1
[info]   | | | | | | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.0 (evicted ..
[info]   | | | | | | | +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1
[info]   | | | | | | |   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.14.1
[info]   | | | | | | |   +-com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.14.1
```

Trimming is problematic for me, as the output of this command is picked up by snyk cli, which gets confused and reports false positives.

I am using sbt 1.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dependencyTree tasks observe `asciiGraphWidth` option starting with sbt 1.6.0.

See [sbt 1.6.0 release notes](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/377c4d6cf9844acc5362ea4cf1fa40d27a5b8fde/notes/1.6.0/enable-asciiGraphWidth-in-dependencyTree.md)

Thus:

- add `asciiGraphWidth` is build.sbt:

```
asciiGraphWidth := 180
```

- alternatively, this can be passed in via command line:

```
sbt 'set asciiGraphWidth := 180' dependencyTree
```